# Web.config authorization for folder with PDFs not working

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, web-config

I've searched for the answer to my question but haven't found nothing (that worked for me) so far.

I have a folder with some pdf documents, that authenticated users should be able to download in my mvc3 application.
After searching for some time on the internet, i found that i should put a Web.config file in that folder with this code:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <deny users="?"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

or something like this in the root Web.config file

```
<location path="~/Downloads/">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="?" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

This should deny all anonymous users.

I have a list in my view, with links to these documents. Something like:

```
<a href="/Downloads/example.pdf">Download this document</a>
```

However, i am still able to access and download the document even though i'm not logged in.

Am i missing something?
Or is there some other (better) way to do this?

Comment: Are you really using ASP.net mvc 3 or is that a mistag?

Comment: "I have a folder with some pdf documents, that authenticated users should be able to download in my mvc3 application" - I think this answers your question

Comment: As @MihaiLabo already said, yes i am using an asp.net mvc3 application.

Comment: ny resolution on this, I am having the same problem. Even if I put a web.config in the directory using system.web / authorization config settings

Answer (score 1):

You need to include .pdf in the file types processed by ASP.NET.

[How to: Configure an HTTP Handler Extension in IIS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb515343.aspx)

Comment: i followed the steps in the link you sent. Now is does redirect me to the logon view when i try to access the documnets. So that's good. BUT.....  When i'm logged in and try to access the documents I get error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE)  in Chrome. IE just says it can't display the page.

Comment: Make sure the ASP.NET account has authority to read those files.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that. (i'm kind of new to this). Is being logged in not enough to read those files?

Comment: The ASP.NET process runs under an account.  That account needs access to those files.   That is different account from IIS (non ASP.NET).  ASP.NET does not operate under the logon user credentials.